# Need a low collision hash function. Inputs are all a permutation of the same 72 bits

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable, associative-array, hash-collision

For an associative array I'm hashing 72 bits down to 26 bits and need an extremely low rate of collisions.  Speed is also a major factor. I started with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hashing_By_Nonlinear_Table_Lookup That is fast enough, but in testing I got collisions within the first 100 inputs!

```
    for(=0; k<9; k++)
            hash ^= randombits[byteptr[k]];
    hash &= (1<<HASHBITS)-1
```

The problem is that all my inputs derive from each other - there is an initial 72 bits, and subsequent inputs are derived from the preceding one by swapping 2 bit pairs (aligned on even bit boundaries) with each other.  The simple XOR loop above fails miserably. An obvious approach would be to use the byte index, "k", to somehow modify the hash in each iteration. In addition to code suggestions, I'm looking for theoretical foundation - I want to have a good idea what the collision rate will be. Reading papers I'm finding nothing regarding hash-effectiveness on permutations. I'm sure the crypto hashes will do well, but they look slow. Suggestions and pointers for my research are welcomed, and thanks. FWIW I use ARC4 to generate the "randombits", an array of 256 u_int32_t.

EDIT for clarity: bit-transpositions in the input look like this: for even numbered N and X less than 72, bits(N:N+1) get swapped with bits(X:X+1), for random X and N. All such swaps actually change the state - identical bits never get swapped.

Comment: How many possible permutations are permitted? Could you simply store the index of the permutation, instead of hashing the result?

Comment: Nick, the permutation-stream is infinite, and I don't know the initial condition.  Of course, if I had storage on the order of 2*72 *wink* ... I'm hoping experimentation will show me that I coincidentally chose the worst sort of function for permutations (straight XOR).  I'll be very happy if I get collisions down anywhere close to 1/8000.

Comment: (1) Only the even bits are swapped: ff the odd bits are not permuted, they are the same for all permutations. So your input has not 72, but only 36 *significant* bits. (2) your hash function is symmetric: ABCDEFGHI hashes to the same value as BACDEFGHI That is a factor of 9! (:= 362880) about 18bits that you lose by symmetry. (3) Also: swapping two bits that happen to be equal does not alter the value. So your "hash-function" can only have about 36 - 18 -1 := 17 bits of information. (4) maybe I am missing yet another symmetry

Comment: I need to clarify: the bit-transpositions in the input look like this: BIT(n): BIT(n+1) get swapped with BIT(x):BIT(x+1), for random x and n, both of which are even integers in the range  zero to 70. Sorry I was unclear! Furthermore, all swap actually change the state - identical bits never swap.

Comment: @Conrad The "permutation stream" may be infinite, but there's only a finite number of possible permutations. It's possible, in principle, to index them. Given you're always swapping in pairs of bits, you can think of your number as being in base 4. The number of permutations depends on how many of each symbol there is; obviously the trivial case where all the symbols are the same has 0 permutations.

Comment: 36 base 4 items, yes. Trillions of permutations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution which has resolved my problem: in the loop I posted, between each XOR I rotate the hash by k bits, where k is the loop index.  In my testing collisions are now as uncommon with input permutations as they are with single bit-flips. It seems the "birthday paradox" is whatis keeping me from reducing the collision rate further, but 26 bits is all I can afford - the hash table is already huge.

Answer (score 0):

Appliyng [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) you can see, that statistically you will get collision probability over 0.5 after hashing (2**13 = 8000) inputs.

Bast try is to use crypto hashing or some hash function based on good and fast PRNG, (Xorshift comes to my mind). You can try with 
MurmurHash3 (author claims it passes some statistical tests and is pretty fast)

https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/source/browse/branches/chandlerc_dev/MurmurHash3.cpp